# How to create super column using Hector API?

Tags: cassandra, hector

My code:

```
public class InsertSuperColumn {

    private static StringSerializer stringSerializer = StringSerializer.get();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("TestCluster", "localhost:9160");

        Keyspace keyspaceOperator = HFactory.createKeyspace("Keyspace1", cluster);

        try {
            Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspaceOperator, stringSerializer);
            mutator.insert("billing", "Super1", HFactory.createSuperColumn("jsmith", 
                    Arrays.asList(HFactory.createStringColumn("first", "John")), 
                    stringSerializer, stringSerializer, stringSerializer));

            SuperColumnQuery<String, String, String, String> superColumnQuery = 
                HFactory.createSuperColumnQuery(keyspaceOperator, stringSerializer, stringSerializer, 
                        stringSerializer, stringSerializer);
            superColumnQuery.setColumnFamily("Super1").setKey("billing").setSuperName("jsmith");

            QueryResult<HSuperColumn<String, String, String>> result = superColumnQuery.execute();

            System.out.println("Read HSuperColumn from cassandra: " + result.get());            
            System.out.println("Verify on CLI with:  get Keyspace1.Super1['billing']['jsmith'] ");

        } catch (HectorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        cluster.getConnectionManager().shutdown();  

    }
}
```

I am getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: 
InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace names must be case-insensitively unique ("new2" conflicts with "new2"))
```

Comment: You should avoid using super columns. They aren't supported in CQL and are slow. Use CompositeType instead.

Comment: As richard said, don't use super column. Its deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating the *keyspace* and *column family* which will store the super column multiple times. You cant do that, *keyspaces* and *column families* must be uniquely named. That is what the exception is telling you:

```
why:Keyspace names must be case-insensitively unique 
("new2" conflicts with "new2")
```

So as far as your code is concerned, you could have created the **supercolumn** correctly. Try verifying using the Cassandra CLI.